# Getting 'FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory' when attempting a POST request to an external API

Tags: python, https

I am encountering an error while trying to make a POST request with https.client . The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\this\is\the\path\to\my\script.py", line 95, in update_ag
    conn.request("POST", f"/path/to/api?{req_data}",
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 976, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1455, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
```

This issue occurs specifically when I get a response code of 409, working fine with 200 and 400.

This is the piece of code I am using for the requests:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("external.api.com")
def update_ag(dwr, qses, data):
    payload = ''
    cookie = dwr + '; ' + qses
    headers = {
        'X-Requested-With': 'Curl',
        'Authorization': 'xxxxx',
        'Cookie': cookie
    }
    try:
        for i in range(len(data)):
            call = 1
            #...
            #just some preprocessing is happening here
            #and the creation of the req_data is happening here
            if call: # if call is 1, make the request
                while True:
                    conn.request("POST", f"/path/to/api?{req_data}",
                                payload,
                                headers)
                    res = conn.getresponse()
                    res_code = res.getcode()
                    if res_code == 200:
                        res = res.read()
                        x = res.decode("utf-8") 
                        break
                    elif res_code == 409:
                        #It nevers gets on this if
                        print("Got 409")
                        res = res.read()
                        x = res.decode("utf-8") 
                        print("Got 409, resending the request in 20 seconds.")
                        time.sleep(20)
                    else:
                        print(f"Request was unsuccessful with error: {res_code}")
                        res = res.read()
                        x = res.decode("utf-8")
                        print(x)
                        bad_req.append(req_data + '\n')
                        break
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Updating asset groups, finished.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("ERROR - Occured in update_ag():")
        print(e)
        raise RuntimeError("unable to handle error")
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this error. Here are some additional details that might help in understanding the problem:

**Environment:** Azure Pipelines
**Code context:** I am attempting to post some data to an external API. I get 409 when the API is busy, thus sending the request 20 seconds later

Based on this information, what could be causing this error, and how can I address it? Are there any additional steps or configurations required to establish an SSL connection successfully? Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Can we see more of the stack trace?

Comment: I don't see req_data being set to a value

Comment: req_data is set but I removed the code since it does not really matter in this one. I will add more info of the stack trace